# Wrap text (and images) around floated div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to design a block like this:

[image]

the image should resize automatically and take the full width until it reaches the red block.

Here's my CSS:

```
#container {
  background: yellow;
}

#floated {
  float: right;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

#image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Fiddle to try live:

http://jsfiddle.net/kYDgL/1835/

Comment: check out http://jsfiddle.net/kYDgL/1834/

Answer (score 0):

set style to `img` to to warp `div` and set `width`

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}

#floated {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
}

img {
  width: 240px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="floated">float float float float float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float
    floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float floatfloat float.</div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,


<div id="iamge">
<img src="https://kbob.github.io/images/sample-1.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
   and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

</div>
```

**To your comment**

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
            img { width: 150px; }
}
```

Learn about `media-query`:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I can't simply set the right width manually, I need a responsive solution

Comment: so use `media-query` to change width of img

Comment: How would you do it?